# Probability that First $s$ Heads in a Row Occurs After $n$ Flips

Tags: probability

Flip a coin repeatedly. Let $E_s$ be the number of coin flips it takes before seeing $s$ heads in a row. What is $P(E_s=n)$? Specifically, I am concerned with $P(E_4=E_3+k)$ (specifically for $k=1,9$) but to calculate this I find that
$$\begin{aligned}
P(E_4=E_3+k) &= \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}P(E_3=n\;\land\; E_4=n+k) \\
&= \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}P(E_4=n+k\;|\; E_3=n)P(E_3=n) \\
&= \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\left(\begin{cases}1/2& k=1 \\
P(E_4=k-1)& k\ge 4 \\
0 & 1<k<4
\end{cases}\right)P(E_3=n) \\
&= \begin{cases}1/2& k=1 \\
P(E_4=k-1)& k\ge 4 \\
0 & 1<k<4
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}$$
where on the last line since $E_s\in [s,\infty]$ so $1=P(E_s=\infty)+\sum_{n=s}^{\infty}P(E_s=n)=\sum_{n=s}^{\infty}P(E_s=n)$. Thus, we are left having to calculate $P(E_4=k-1)$. Is the work for my specific case correct? And if so how do we finish the problem, or is there a method that avoid direct calculation?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The answer below isn't really an answer, as it failed to address the "in a row" component. See the comments for details.

So there are a total of $2^n$ possible sequences of flipping a fair coin $n$ times, and of those there are $n-1\choose s-1$ that both contain exactly $s$ heads and end with a head (with the convention that binomial coefficients that don't make sense are all equal to $0$). Thus, $P(E_s = n)={n-1\choose s-1}/2^n$ (you can verify that this statement is true by summing up all of these probabilities to show that you get back $1$).

If you need help with the specific problem, comment and let me know, but presumably this is what the doctor ordered.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for the first occurrence of $s$ heads **in a row** isn't he?

Comment: @saulspatz I wan't clear on that matter; the title references heads in a row, but the body only specifies "seeing $s$ heads". I assume that he will tell me which one he actually wants.

Comment: My bad I just realized the two weren't consistent. I was intending on heads in a row if you have an idea on that.

Comment: @WillFisher I do have an idea on how to pin down these probabilities, but it might take me a while to edit the answer completely. Basically you want to do a count of strings that avoid the forbidden subword of HH...H until the very end. The standard way of doing this that I know is via the Gouldan-Jackson cluster method. The two papers I have linked in this comment have good descriptions of it. https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.5113.pdf

http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPDF/gj.pdf

Comment: @BlarglFlarg Okay I'll take a look. The problem comes off a pretty simple exam so it maybe that calculating $P(E_4=E_3+k)$ can be done in a simpler way that computing the exact values of $P(E_s=n)$. I would also be fine with just a calculation of $P(E_4=8)$ and a verification of my calculation to $P(E_4=E_3+9)$.

Comment: I suppose that $P(E_4=8)$ is simple: The the last four flips must be heads, the 5th from last must be tails (otherwise $E_4\le 7$) and the first three can be anything. So it would be $2^3/2^8$. It may be that the exam only asks these for simplicity and anything beyond it is very difficult.

Comment: @WillFisher Yea, with these small numbers it looks like you can just crank out everything by hand exhaustively.